How can I do a binary git diff of text files
I'm struggling with line endings
git refuses to discard the changes, but I'm unsure if git is correcting the issue or if it is introducing it.
Even if I switch to another branch using git switch --discard-changes the files are still shown as changed.
I have a .gitattributes file containing
# .gitattributes

# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.bat text eol=crlf
*.BAT text eol=crlf
*.cmd text eol=crlf

I want to see a diff of the sources that actually shows the cr and lf characters
I already tried
 git diff --color --word-diff-regex=.


git diff --color --word-diff-regex=.
diff --git a/xyz.bat b/xys.bat
index 287d272cd..328ffd67c 100755
--- a/xyz.bat
+++ b/xyz.bat
@@ -1,46 +1,46 @@
@echo off[-^M-]
SETLOCAL[-^M-]

but that gives me the impression a CR was removed, which would only be the correct change if the source currently contained cr+cr+lf instead of cr+lf
Can I do a side-by-side binary diff ?

I used an external difference viewer (Araxis) and made it display line ending, both sides of the comparison showed CRLF. I wen ahead and committed the "change". Looks fine

Set the default behavior, in case people don't have core.autocrlf set.

text=auto

Explicitly declare text files you want to always be normalized and converted
to native line endings on checkout.
*.c text
*.h text
Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf
Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified.
*.png binary
*.jpg binary

This has to be ChatGPT.. it doesn't come even close to answering the question and doesn't even tell you what file this is (which WE all know).  If it isn't, amend your answer to actually have an answer and I will give the point back.
